# Does .NET 5 Console App look for appsettings.json automatically?

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-5

I couldn't load any connection string using appsettings.json in my VS2019 solution:

**appsettings.json**

```
{
 "ConnectionStrings": {
   "Entities": "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security=true;"
 }
```

}

**Program.cs**

```
private static IConfiguration config;

static void Main()
{
    // throws null exception
    var sec = config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings");

    // returns null
    string conn = config.GetConnectionString("Entities");

    using (Entities context = new())
    {
       var rbts = context.Students.ToList();
       foreach (var rbt in rbts)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", rbt.Name, rbt.ID);
       }
    }
}
```

So I've modified entities.cs file like below and it retrieves data from DB, it's OK.

**Entities.cs**

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
           optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I cannot migrate database using EF5 command below:

```
update-database -context entities -connection entities
```

The error:

```
 Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
```

If I comment out the line as below:

```
// optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
```

Then the error becomes:

```
No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.
```

I explicitly use -connection bec. of I want to use another connection string & DB. I could connect to DB but there is no Students table yet. I need to migrate it from code first.

**My question is that what's wrong with appsettings.json?** It seems like ignored to me.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with appsettings.json but .NET 5 is already out of support. It was a single-year "current" version. The long term support versions are .NET Core 3.1 which reaches EOL too in November 2022 and .NET 6 which is supported until 2024

Comment: As for what's wrong with the code, it never registers any configuration source. There's nothing special about `appsettings.json`, it's just a file that's registered as a JSON settings file using `AddJson`. The Web and Generic host builders add add and configure the configuration, logging and DI middlewares. `appsettings.json` is the default name used by the web host builder for the settings file. It also adds the environment variable and commandline config sources

Comment: Also, IIRC up to .NET 5 EF core tools required a static `Program.CreateHostBuilder` method to properly work by fetching the host builder / configuration from it. S. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0#set-up-a-host-1 and https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-5-supporting-ef-core-tools-with-webapplicationbuilder/

Comment: You are missing some code, show were you are instantiating `private static IConfiguration config;`.

Comment: Ok, I will continue to use OnConfiguring method. Plus "add-migration CreateDB -context entities" and "update-database -context entities" commands do the job. Thanks